# How do I uninstall an application?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

If I want to completely uninstall an application from the home screen or list of applications; how do I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can uninstall an application from the Market or from the Manage Applications settings screen.

From Marketplace:

1. Start the Market app.
2. Hit the menu button and select Downloads.
3. Find the app you want to uninstall and select it.
4. Hit the Uninstall button at the bottom.

From Manage Applications:

1. From your Home screen hit the menu button and select Settings.
2. Select "Applications"
3. Select "Manage Applications"
4. Find the app you want to uninstall and select it.
5. Hit the Uninstall button at the top.

**EDIT:** I wanted to add a 3rd method that [Rohan Singh](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/45/rohan-singh) had [in his answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-do-i-uninstall-an-application/55#55).

From your Home screen:

1. Tap and hold on the icon of the application you want to uninstall.
2. When the trash can appears near the bottom center of the screen, drag and hold the icon there.
3. After the tap & hold / drag & hold some text will appear indicating that you can uninstall by dropping the application's icon on the trash can.
4. Release your finger over the trash can and you'll be taken to the same uninstall screen you can get to through Manage Applications in your Settings.

Comment: The drag and drop method only works in some Home launcher programs, such LauncherPro.

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings->Applications->Manage applications

Select the application you want to remove.

Click uninstall.

Not all applications may be removed (some are locked down by your carrier / phone vendor).

Answer (score 4):

A quick, easy way to uninstall an application is to hold down on its icon, and then drag it to the trash can at the bottom of the screen like you would if you were removing a shortcut from your home screen. However, hold the icon over the trash can for a few seconds until "Drop to uninstall" appears.

Comment: This will remove the app's icon from your Home screen, but not actually uninstall the app.

Comment: If you hold the icon over the bin for a while , you get a "drop to uninstall" notification , the behavior may have been changed by the manufacturer.

Comment: @Matt Casto, while you are correct that simply dragging and dropping a home screen icon onto the garbage can will delete the icon from the homescreen, Rohan also stated that if you drag and pause for a few seconds over the trashcan, "drop to uninstall" appears, and will uninstall the application. Which is something I didn't know until he pointed it out. Thanks Rohan!

Answer (score 3):

By using adb from command line:

```
adb uninstall <package name to uninstall>
```