# How to uninstall preinstalled apps on Gingerbread?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

I have Samsung Galaxy Note running Android Gingerbread. I have several apps like Crayon Physics that don't show up in the list of installed apps in the market.

How to get rid of them?

Comment: See the accepted answer to this previous question, the Manage Applications section: [How do I uninstall an application](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39/)

Comment: Yes, Crayon Physics was pre-installed.

Comment: Also should have mentioned, this is Gingerbread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Crayon Physics was a pre-installed bloatware application then you must root to delete it. Ice Cream Sandwich lets you "freeze" the app though that may not be what you are looking for.

If you side-loaded the application then I have seen times when an application won't show under the Market application because it doesn't have a signature the Market recognizes; that is, you didn't get it from the Market.

If you installed the application go to Settings->Applications->Manage Applications. Under the 'Downloaded' tab you should be able to find it. Again, if it was pre-installed then you didn't 'download' it so it won't show up here but you should see it here even if you side-loaded it.

Good luck (:

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful although it doesn't help with this particular app. I did have a strange situation with another app that I downloaded ("animating touch" or something), where it didn't show up in the list of installed apps in the market app. In that case, I was able to search for it, install an update, then uninstall it.

Comment: Anyway, yes, it looks like I need to root - and that sounds riskier than I want just to get rid of a silly app. I guess I'll just bury it in a folder somewhere.

Comment: "Risk" is an assessment that should be based on your needs. I'm not going to go into a diatribe on why you should root to gain control of the hardware you own. I would only say, <rant>"POWER TO THE PEOPLE!!!"</rant>

Comment: Well, it's like this. Potential gain: "crayon physics doesn't appear in my apps list". Potential loss: unusable phone which I just spent my life savings on. (Might I add that I'm extremely grateful for people who are willing to take such risks and keep vendors honest.)

Comment: @andrew-t what was the point of that edit? This answer was correct at the time of publishing. What benefit did your edit add other than to boost your own numbers?