# Android directly uninstall from home screen by drag and drop

Tags: uninstallation, drag-n-drop

Currently it takes me two steps to uninstall one application  - go to application list and drag and drop it onto the bin icon.

I dont  like this way since it requires me to look for the application name from the grid listed.

Is there other ways to quickly drag and drop it directly from home screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall an application?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-do-i-uninstall-an-application)

Comment: Not really a exact duplicate, but [one answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/55/440) from the other question has the solution OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your launcher specifically supports it then no.

Some launchers allow you to easily uninstall by long clicking and then dragging to an uninstall option, some require you to do it all manually.

You may wish to search for alternate launchers from Google Play if you really want to be able to do this.

Comment: +1. Didn't realize this wasn't common to all launchers.  (*I think it ought to be!*)

Comment: The default Cyanogenmod Launcher supports the solution mentioned by [gary](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34997/440) and [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/55/440).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, drag it to the trash can but hover there a few extra seconds.* You should then get prompted to answer 'Are you sure you want to remove this app?' Also, if the app cannot be deleted because it came pre-installed, then this will just remove its shortcut.

*This is dependent upon the launcher.*